# How can i split SQL field that contains an XML string

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

I have a field with XML snippets. I want create a `#TempTable` which will contain a split of the XML data but only show any characters in between two specific tags.

the field value looks something like this (wrapped for legibility):

```
<monthdate>2019-07-01</monthdate>
<automitemno>302</automitemno>
<amount>1.190000000000</amount>
<currentamount>0.000000000000</currentamount>
<langitemno>1</langitemno>
<monthdate>2019-07-01</monthdate>
<automitemno>2131</automitemno>
<amount>0.386750000000</amount>
<currentamount>0.000000000000</currentamount>
<langitemno>1</langitemno>
```

and so on. I want the column in the `#TempTable` to contain each occurrence of data between the tags `<monthdate>` and `</amount>`. It should look like the below:

```
XMLValue
---------
2019-07-01</monthdate><automitemno>302</automitemno><amount>1.190000000000
2019-07-01</monthdate><automitemno>2131</automitemno><amount>0.386750000000
```

Comment: Do you actually want the output without the signs (`< & >`)? Or is this just an issue with the question formatting?

Comment: Hi, yes it was the question formatting, apologies. I would like the (<>) in the output as I need to use the temp table in several other queries for a dashboard report.

Comment: also, which SQL engine are you using? MS SQL Server, MySQL, PostgreSQL, and which version?

Comment: MS SQL SERVER Management studio 17

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure which one of these you meant. First one returns them as separate xml rows, other one returns them as typed data rows:

```
DECLARE @sample TABLE
(
    id INT IDENTITY,
    xmlSnippet VARCHAR(MAX)
);

INSERT @sample
(
    xmlSnippet
)
VALUES
('<monthdate>2019-07-01</monthdate>
<automitemno>302</automitemno>
<amount>1.190000000000</amount>
<currentamount>0.000000000000</currentamount>
<langitemno>1</langitemno>
<monthdate>2019-07-01</monthdate>
<automitemno>2131</automitemno>
<amount>0.386750000000</amount>
<currentamount>0.000000000000</currentamount>
<langitemno>1</langitemno>');


DECLARE @tempTable TABLE
(
    id INT,
    XMLValue XML
);

INSERT @tempTable
(
    id,
    XMLValue
)
SELECT id,
       CAST('<monthdate>' + value AS XML)
FROM @sample
    CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(REPLACE(xmlSnippet, '<monthdate>', '&'), '&')
WHERE value <> '';
SELECT *
FROM @tempTable;

DECLARE @tempTable2 TABLE
(
    monthDate DATE,
    autoItemNo INT,
    amount MONEY,
    currentAmount MONEY
);

WITH myData (id, xmlRow)
AS (SELECT id,
           CAST('<monthdate>' + value AS XML)
    FROM @sample
        CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(REPLACE(xmlSnippet, '<monthdate>', '&'), '&')
    WHERE value <> '')
INSERT @tempTable2
(
    monthDate,
    autoItemNo,
    amount,
    currentAmount
)
SELECT myData.xmlRow.value('/monthdate[1]', 'date'),
       myData.xmlRow.value('/automitemno[1]', 'int'),
       myData.xmlRow.value('/amount[1]', 'money'),
       myData.xmlRow.value('/currentamount[1]', 'money')
FROM myData;

SELECT *
FROM @tempTable2;
```

EDIT: I added [DBFiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=63da89218ac3cc26968d4d17773cfcd7)

Comment: Thanks for the Above, v helpful, just an additional clarification. How would I go about call this from a table and column, ie.. instead of setting the value as a known Nvarchar value, what if want to specify which table and column the value is in and insert the outcome to a TEMPORARY TABLE?

Comment: Actually I am calling it from a table, @sample is a table variable and could be a real persisted table.

Comment: And as per TEMPORARY TABLE, just replace table variable (@tempTable) with a temp table like #tempTable.

Comment: hey: I query returned: Invalid object name 'STRING_SPLIT'?? any ideas? it recognises the command as it's in pink but errors out?

Comment: String_Split was introduced in version 2016 (compatibility level 130). What version are you using? Check db fiddle demo I gave link to.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that gives text exactly as written:

```
declare @xml as nvarchar(max)

set @xml = N'<monthdate>2019-07-01</monthdate>
<automitemno>302</automitemno>
<amount>1.190000000000</amount>
<currentamount>0.000000000000</currentamount>
<langitemno>1</langitemno>
<monthdate>2019-07-01</monthdate>
<automitemno>2131</automitemno>
<amount>0.386750000000</amount>
<currentamount>0.000000000000</currentamount>
<langitemno>1</langitemno>'


select replace(substring(a.value, charindex('<monthdate>',a.value)+11, charindex('</amount>', a.value)-16), char(10), '') as [XMLValue]

from string_split(replace(@xml, '</langitemno>', char(30)), char(30)) a

where a.value like '%<monthdate>%</amount>%'
```

[DBFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=2be3a6f6a4cd2b3dac5a1fb5210a348b)